# How do I switch the furnace to heat mode?

Tags: furnace

I have an older good Sears furnace.  It was on cool mode this summer and the fan could come on.  I can't find how to switch it back to heat mode!

Thanks.
Linda

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the specific setup of your system.

Some systems have a switch (typically labelled "Winter/Summer" IME) others just note if the thermostat is calling for heating or cooling.

Some thermostats have a "Cool-Off-Heat" mode switch on the thermostat itself.

Comment: To clarify, the switch mentioned will be located on your thermostat inside your home where the indoor temperature is set.

Comment: Thankyou so much!  I can't get it.  That's ok.  We've tried various combinations.  Only 3 buttons.  First time this ever happened.  I'll phone.  Thanks.